# GCD, iterative and recursive issue

Tags: c, recursion, iteration

I'm doing an assignment where I must create an iterative and recursive fuction that reads two arrays (x_vals[i], and y_vals[i]) and prints out the GCD respectively. The results from both the recursive and iterative functions should be the same otherwise something is wrong with one or both of the functions. Below is what I have. What I can't understand is what's wrong with the program like why aren't my results matching.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* function prototypes */
int iterGCD(int x, int y);
int recGCD(int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num_vals = 6;
    int x_vals[] = {3, 9, 12, 36, 1, 105};
    int y_vals[] = {3, 21, 18, 27, 12, 91};
    int i = 0;

    printf("Assignment 2 Problem 2 by <Jonathan Taylor>.\n\n");

    while (i<num_vals)
    {
        printf("Iterative GCD: x = %d, y = %d, result = %d\n", x_vals[i], y_vals[i], iterGCD(x_vals[i],y_vals[i]));
        printf("Recursive GCD: x = %d, y = %d, result = %d\n\n", x_vals[i], y_vals[i], recGCD(x_vals[i],y_vals[i]));

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int iterGCD(int x, int y)
{
    int GCD = 1;
    int number = 1;

    /*For loop method, you could ignore if you like
    for (number = 1; number <= x && number <= y; ++number){
        if(x % number == 0 && y % number == 0){
        GCD = number;
    }
    */

    while ((number <= x) && (number <= y)) {
        ++number;

        if(x % number == 0 && y % number == 0) {
        GCD = number;
        }

        return GCD;
    }
}

int recGCD(int x, int y)
{
    if(y != 0){
        int remainder = x % y;
        return recGCD(y, remainder);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: What are your results?

Comment: Show results for each, and what's expected

Comment: Iterative GCD: x = 3; y = 3, result = 1;
Recursive GCD: x = 3, y = 3, result = 3;

Iterative GCD: x = 9, y = 21, result = 1
Recursive GCD: x = 9, y = 21, result = 3

Iterative GCD: x = 12, y =18, result = 2
Recursive GCD: x = 12, y = 18, result = 6

Iterative GCD: x = 36, y =27, result = 1
Recursive GCD: x = 36, y = 27, result = 9

Sorry, not enough room to write

Comment: You placed the `return` at wrong place in case of `iterGCD`.

Comment: @EliTaylor make an edit to the question instead of commenting the result, so that everyone can see without having to go through comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return in `iterGCD` is in the wrong place:

```
while ((number <= x) && (number <= y)) {
    ++number;

    if(x % number == 0 && y % number == 0) {
    GCD = number;
    }

    return GCD;     // <----------- wrong
}
```

You go through a single iteration of the loop and `return` at the end of the loop.  Move the `return` to *after* the loop:

```
while ((number <= x) && (number <= y)) {
    ++number;

    if(x % number == 0 && y % number == 0) {
    GCD = number;
    }

}
return GCD;    // <----------- move here
```

Comment: @EliTaylor Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.